# Problem with IMPORTRANGE function in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

I’m trying to get IMPORTRANGE to work for me with no success. I made two simple spreadsheets: [Destination Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-XOgiQkR9JYDpqJ2a1vDjiuattKyRknqYCHYD_PZJTo) and [Source Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-5F1_zz0ZpGj7SfeQhewsCe0CsrA0eyPbjfmUrLBsyk). In the destination sheet I’m using the import range function:

```
=importrange(“1-5F1_zz0ZpGj7SfeQhewsCe0CsrA0eyPbjfmUrLBsyk”,”Sheet1!a1:a1”)
```

I tried already:

- Replacing the , with ;
- Referencing just the key as well as the full URL in the first argument
- Switching from “ to ‘
- With the sheet name and without it

Not sure what else to do.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following are three distinct characters:

```
"   34
“   8220
”   8221
```

and although the help file for [IMPORTRANGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340) mentions only *...either be enclosed in quotation marks or be a reference to a cell containing...* the required quotation marks are the "straight" ones.

So just use `"`.

Comment: Thanks - this worked! Can’t believe how much time I spent on this.